# C Programming Error: Reading from a .txt file

Tags: c, file, matrix, text-files

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

/*

Content of Text FILE

5        // no_of_process   
4        // no_of_resource_type
6 3 4 2  // vector E matrix
3 0 1 1  // 5x4 matrix
0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 

*/


int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    int no_of_process;
    int no_of_resource_type;
    int *vector_E;
    int **C;
    int counter = 1, i, k;
    char unwanted[50];

    file = fopen("file_path\\file.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("NO SUCH A FILE EXISTS!!!");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(!feof(file))
    {
        if(counter == 1){
            fscanf(file, "%d", &no_of_process);           // The number of process is set
            fscanf(file, "100[^\n]", unwanted);           // put in "unwanted" the un wanted chars untill you get \n 
            counter++;                                    // counter for selecting operation type
            printf("\nProcess: %d", no_of_process);
        }

        else if(counter == 2){
             fscanf(file, "%d", &no_of_resource_type);    // The number of resource type is set
             fscanf(file, "100[^\n]", unwanted);          // put in "unwanted" the un wanted chars untill you get \n 
             counter++;                                   // counter for selecting operation type                                
             printf("\nType: %d\n", no_of_resource_type);
        }

        else if(counter == 3){
             vector_E = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*no_of_resource_type);  // Allocating memory for vector_E of size # of resource type

             for(i=0; i<no_of_resource_type; i++){                        // fillling vector_E array 
                 fscanf(file, "%d", &vector_E[i]);
                 printf("%d ", vector_E[i]);
             }                        
             fscanf(file, "100[^\n]", unwanted);                         // put in "unwanted" the un wanted chars untill you get \n
             counter++;                                                  // counter for selecting operation type
             printf("\n");                                                  
        }

        else if(counter == 4){
             C = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int *)*no_of_process);             // Allocating memory for Current Allocation Matrix "part1"


             for(i=0; i<no_of_resource_type; i++)                       // Allocating memory for Current Allocation Matrix "part2"
                 C[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*no_of_resource_type);


             for(i=0; i<no_of_process; i++){                             // Filling the Current Allocation Matrix
                 for(k=0; k<no_of_resource_type; k++){
                     fscanf(file, "%d", &C[i][k]);
                     printf("%d ", C[i][k]);
                 }
                 printf("\n");

                 // -------------------------------------------------------------------- ???????????
                // Problem is here !!!!!
                // --------------------------------------------------------------------- ???????????

                 fscanf(file, "100[^\n]", unwanted);                     // put in "unwanted" the un wanted chars untill you get \n

             }
        }
    }


    printf("# of Process: %d\n", no_of_process);
    printf("# of Resource Type: %d\n", no_of_resource_type);

    printf("Vector E\n");
    for(i=0; i<no_of_resource_type; i++)
        printf("%d ", vector_E[i]);

    printf("\nCurrent Allocation Matrix\n");
    for(i=0; i<no_of_process; i++){
        for(k=0; k<no_of_resource_type; k++){
            printf("%d ", C[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The task is to read numbers from a txt file. There is no problem in reading no_of_process, no_of_resource_type, and vector_E matrix. The problem occurs when the program reads the 4th row of the "5x4 matrix" and an "An Access Violation(Segmentation Fault) raised in your program" error occurs. I marked the line where the problem occurs as "Problem is here!!!".

Can someone explain what is the reason of this problem and what to do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
         C = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int *)*no_of_process); 
         for(i=0; i<no_of_resource_type; i++) 
             C[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*no_of_resource_type);
```

Well, you allocate "no_of_process" many spaces for int pointers, but then in the for loop you allocate only "no_of_resource_type" rows. So change the for loop to

```
         for(i=0; i<no_of_process; i++)
```